# WPF Equivalent of HTML base tag but for Source with relative path

Tags: wpf

In my app, we can't use relative path for legacy reasons and we Sources like this `Source="/My.Project.Name;component/Resources/myImage.png"`.

So I've been wondering if there was a WPF equivalent of HTMl's `base` tag, allowing me to write `/My.Project.Name;component/` only once in my file and using relative path elsewhere.

Comment: In case `Source="/My.Project.Name;component/Resources/myImage.png"` is meant to set the Source property of an Image element in XAML, the string is converted to a BitmapFrame by the framework's built-in type conversion, i.e. the ImageSourceConverter class. Afaik there is no way to make an instance of that class use a base URI. And it is also not possible to register a different TypeConverter.

Comment: @Clemens How about manual concatenation with a staticResource so I still have to specify the base only once and then do `{StaticResource Base} + myPath`

Answer (score 1):

You may use a custom MarkupExtension

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(ImageSource))]
public class ImageResourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public ImageResourceExtension(string image)
    {
        Image = image;
    }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(
            "pack://application:,,,/My.Project.Name;component/Resources/"
            + Image));
    }
}
```

like this:

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource myImage.png}"/>
```

Comment: Had to create a default constructor and specify `Image` explicitly or I get `Part URI can't end with a forward slash` if trying to specify a subfolder. But it works! Also sadly doesn't list/autocomplete the file names but I don't know if that can be fixed?

Comment: It works exactly like this for me. Obviously without autocomplete...

Comment: Is there a way to make it work as a Resource as well? I tried `<Grid.Resources><local:ImageResources x:Key="Foo" Image="filename.png" /></Grid.Resources>` but when I `Source={StaticResources Foo}` it complains that `ImageSource` is expected but `ImageResourcesExtension` was received instead.

Comment: A MarkupExtension is supposed to be used "in place".